# Why do we get exactly $2$ complex roots when $q > 10^5$?

Tags: number-theory, galois-theory

I am working on the problem in my textbook:

> Construct a polynomial of degree $7$ with rational coefficients whose Galois group over $\mathbb{Q}$ is $\operatorname{Sym}(7).$

There is a theorem in the text that states if a polynomial with prime degree $p$ has exactly two roots in $\mathbb{C}$ and that polynomial is also irreducible over $\mathbb{Q},$ then the Galois group of that polynomial is the symmetric group $\operatorname{Sym}(p).$

The polynomial of the form $f(x) = x^7+qm(x)$ works for sufficiently large primes $q$ (primes larger than $10^5)$ where $m(x)$ is a product of linear factors say $(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)(x-5).$ It is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ by Eisenstein's Criterion applied to $q.$ If $q > 10^5,$ then $f(x)$ has $5$ real roots. Since $\deg f(x) = 7,$ there must be $2$ roots in $\mathbb{C}.$

> *Question:* Why do we get exactly $2$ complex roots when $q$ is a large enough prime number?
>
> $($i.e. $q > 10^5)$

Comment: It might help to think of $x^7/q+m(x)$.  The extra term will shift the five real roots just a little bit when $1/q$ is small enough, and introduce no new ones.  Then, since a heptic has seven roots, there must be two large complex roots introduced, with $x^7/q$ roughly the same size as $x^5$ (the largest term of the quintic).

Comment: I don't see how you can use Eisenstein's criterion.

Comment: Oh you mean applied to $q$, not $p$.

Comment: @user21820 fixed

Comment: Yup then @Michael's comment is the correct answer. He should post his comment as an answer. =)

Comment: @user21820 His reasoning makes sense to me, but I wouldn't mind seeing some extra details

Comment: Except the last part is not quite right I think. I'm not sure exactly how he is doing it, but I would first bound the roots of $m$ by some $c$ and then choose $q$ sufficiently large so that changing $m$ by any amount less than $c^7 / q$ does not create a new root.

Comment: Okay on thinking about it it seems you need a few more conditions. $m$ must have positive leading coefficient and only positive single roots. Then you can find a straight line through the origin with positive slope that cuts the graph of $m$ at only $5$ points. After that you can find the $q$ you want. Not so simple, but maybe you can try first?

Answer (score 2):

It might help to think of $x^7/q+m(x)$.
The extra term will shift the five real roots just a little bit when $1/q$ is small enough, and introduce no new ones.
Then, since a heptic has seven roots, there must be two large complex roots introduced, with $x^7/q$ roughly the same size as $x^5$ (the largest term of the quintic) but negative, so they will be near $\pm\sqrt{-q}$